# Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers

Tags: apache-camel, spring-jms

I have an apache-camel JMS route.

```
form("jms:queue:sourceQueue").to("messageProcessor")
```

My requirement is to stop route on 3 message processing failures. In messageProcessor class, in catch block I am checking for error count and as soon as it reaches 3, I am inovking

```
camelContext.stopRoute(routeID, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

My route **do not stop** and spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer writes following line in log

> *Shutting down JMS listener container*
>
> *Waiting for shutdown of message listener invokers*
>
> ***Still waiting for shutdown*** of 1 message listener invokers

I am trying to figure out, what is holding DMLC from stopping?
What camel attribute I am missing?

If I use `asyncStopListener=true` then camle route stops but a thread keeps waiting in background to stop listener.

Comment: It means that the thread that is responsible to receive a `javax.jms.Message` is still active. It looks like you are trying to stop the container responsible to process a destination from a thread managed by the container (i.e loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you stopping a route from a route? eg if you do that in the 
processor, then see this FAQ 
http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html

Comment: Thank you. Spawning another thread to shutdown route did help.